# SQL Server View returns strange EF results

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I have written a simple query and saved it as a view (see below...)
When I run the query in SSMS, it returns 30 rows, and they are correct.
When I set it up in Entity Framework (using wizards the whole way...I did it three times...) at least one row is duplicated several times in the resulting gridview. I get a total of 30 rows, but many are dups, and others are missing. One row is duplicated 9 times.

I recreated the view (three are actually two misbehaving) with a new name using the script below to make sure EF didn't have any leftover artifacts. I used a virgin asp.net page, with a new datasource and a virgin, almost completely vanilla datagrid with "autogenerate=true" on, so I didn't control anything. I can show the markup if that would help. The generated markup has all the dups in it, so it's not a client rendering issue.

Maybe I should take EF out of the loop by using Linq to SQL or something, but I don't know how. I'll try doing that after I post this. Thanks....

[Edit -- I changed the datasource to a SQLDataSource and it worked perfectly. Exactly the correct results!]

```
    USE [CPAS];
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.tstTimesheetSummarybyWorkerDiscipline
AS SELECT dbo.tblTimesheetDetail.TimesheetID , 
          dbo.tblWorkers.WorkerName AS [Worker Name] , 
          dbo.tblStaffAugLaborRates.TradeType AS [Trade Type] , 
          SUM( dbo.tblTimesheetDetail.TSDStdHrs
             )AS [Regular Hours] , 
          SUM( dbo.tblTimesheetDetail.TSDOTHrs
             )AS [Overtime Hours] , 
          SUM( dbo.tblTimesheetDetail.TSDDTHrs
             )AS [Doubletime Hours] , 
          SUM( dbo.tblTimesheetDetail.TSDStdHrs + dbo.tblTimesheetDetail.TSDOTHrs + dbo.tblTimesheetDetail.TSDDTHrs
             )AS [Tot Hrs] , 
          SUM( dbo.tblTimesheetDetail.TSDMiscAmt
             )AS [Expense Amt] , 
          COUNT( *
               )AS [Timesheet Count]
     FROM
          dbo.tblTimesheetDetail INNER JOIN dbo.tblWorkers
          ON dbo.tblTimesheetDetail.TSDWorkerID
             = 
             dbo.tblWorkers.ID
                                 INNER JOIN dbo.tblStaffAugLaborRates
          ON dbo.tblTimesheetDetail.TSDLaborRateID
             = 
             dbo.tblStaffAugLaborRates.ID
     GROUP BY dbo.tblTimesheetDetail.TimesheetID , 
              dbo.tblWorkers.WorkerName , 
              dbo.tblStaffAugLaborRates.TradeType;

GO
```

Comment: For sure, the fields that entity framework uses as primary key of the view are not unique in the view. Change the key fields manually into a combination that is unique.

Comment: Read only view. Keys necessary?

Comment: Yes, EF just wants to identify anything it materializes.

Comment: You are right about the problem, it appears. I removed spurious keys and added one that had been missed by EF. I did a fair amount of research on this (though any additional resources would be appreciated...) and found that even if I create a primary key on the view (with some difficulty...) EF will ignore that and infer its own. I don't understand the "ENTITY KEY" concept, particularly when EF "knows' this is a read-only view. Exactly what does "ENTITY KEY" mean, and what effect does it have on reading a "read-only" view?